# Erro: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Bom dia,
Possuo projetos utilizando `System.Web.MVC na versão 4.0.0.1`, trabalhava normalmente na versão 2013 do Visual Studio, agora estou tentando trabalhar com Visual Studio 2015 e minhas Views não reconhecem mais algumas propriedades por exemplo `ViewBag e @model`, elas continuam funcionando porem ficam grifadas em vermelho com a seguinte mensagem "The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context".

Procurei diversas soluções online mas ainda não encontrei nada que resolva. Não gostaria de ter que atualizar para MVC 5 pois tenho muitos projetos em paralelo e teria que atualizar todos.

Existe alguma solução para este problema que creio que seja de compatibilidade ?

Comment: Tô sem tempo de criar uma resposta, dá uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960148/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: Clique na sua na sua view (ex: Index.cshtml) com o botão direito e vai em "Open With", e verifique se a opção "Razor Editor" está como Default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe um update para o Visual Studio 2015 [que habilita novamente a sintaxe do MVC4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591926.aspx).

Ainda assim, não vejo vantagem em manter um projeto no MVC4. [Aqui tem um guia de migração para o MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) que já usei algumas vezes em projetos meus.

Comment: Obrigado Cigano, funcionou corretamente a atualização. Também não vejo vantagem mas estou sem tempo para migrar os projetos pra MVC 5, assim que possível realizarei a migração. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Já passei por isso algumas vezes e parece que o problema está relacionado ao HTML Editor quando ele tenta interpretar código em Razor, eu consegui resolver esse problema algumas fechando todas as abas que estava abertas e reabrindo aquela em que o problema ocorria. Caso isso não resolva o problema já vi algumas pessoas recomendando reiniciar as configurações de usuário iniciando o Visual Studio com o argumento de linha de comando `/ResetUserData`.

```
devenv /ResetUserData
```

No Stack Overflow em inglês, existe algumas perguntas sobre o mesmo problema no Visual Studio 2015 e foram resolvidas dessa maneira também:

- [Visual Studio 2015 Broken Razor Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581666/visual-studio-2015-broken-razor-intellisense)
- [Visual Studio 2015 not syntax highlighting razor nor Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311355/visual-studio-2015-not-syntax-highlighting-razor-nor-intellisense)